# Expected: 'n', instead got: '\'n\''

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, conversión-de-tipos, tipos

Esta funcion busca el numero que mas se repite en un arreglo, el problema es que el numero que me retorna al final como string(en este caso 12) me dice lo siguiente: **Expected: '12', instead got: '\'12\''** y es verdad aunque no entiendo el porque si en vez de `return num` hago `return num*1` si estoy regresando `'12'` pensaba que eran espacios en blanco o algo `''+num.trim()` nada si retorno `String(num)` tampoco. Porque sucede esto???

```js
function highestRank(arr){
    let obj = {};
    arr.map(v => obj[v]=obj[v] ? obj[v]+1: 1)
    let repeticiones=0;
    let num=0;
    for(let n in obj){
        if(obj[n]>=repeticiones){
            repeticiones = obj[n];
            num=n
        }
    }
    return num
}


console.log(highestRank([12, 6, 8, 12, 7, 6, 4, 10, 12]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: No puedo reproducir el error, donde lo ejecutas?

Comment: Hola, exactamente cuál es el problema, tu código tal como está funciona en el *snippet*

Comment: Es algún Kata de codewars? Si es así podrías linkearlo? ¿Has probado a hacerle `parseInt` antes de retornarlo?

Comment: si es exactamente es una kata de codewars @x3k_js este es el link https://www.codewars.com/kata/highest-rank-number-in-an-array/train/javascript

Comment: @MauricioContreras si exactamente por eso es mi duda pq no se que es lo que esta sucediendo detras que hay alguna diferencia... saludos amigo

Comment: @Emeeus en el compilador de codewars no acepta la respuesta no se en que otra parte se puede ver la diferencia

Comment: @IsraelGonzález, como me imaginaba al parsearlo funciona bien tu respuesta. Es posible que el test unit que usa este comparando lo que devuelves con === por lo que tiene en cuenta el tipo también¿?... No estoy seguro, pero se me ocurre que pueda ser algo del estilo...

Comment: @x3k_js es verdad pensaba que estaba esperando un tipo string por el  `Expected: 'n'`pero definitivamente lo que espera es un number

Comment: Pues es eso, resulta que estás devolviendo un tipo *String*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto sucede porque aunque inicialmente utilices como llaves en tu diccionario valores numéricos, las llaves del diccionario siempre se convertirán en en String, símplemente por eso la respuesta que das da un String.

```js
let dict = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3};
let hasKeyTypeNumber = Object.keys(dict).some(key => typeof key == "number");

console.log(hasKeyTypeNumber);
```

Un cambio sencillo que puedes hacer es retornar la respuesta parseada.

```
function highestRank(arr){
    let obj = {};
    arr.map(v => obj[v]=obj[v] ? obj[v]+1: 1)
    let repeticiones=0;
    let num=0;
    for(let n in obj){
        if(obj[n]>=repeticiones){
            repeticiones = obj[n];
            num=n
        }
    }
    return parseInt(num);
}
```